# JayData Web API Error $metadata

Tags: jaydata

I get the following error from JayData.

```
Object {requestUri: "/api/program/getprograms/$metadata", statusCode: 404, statusText: "Not Found", responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Stric…↵ </fieldset> ↵</div> ↵</div> ↵</body> ↵</html> ↵"}
```

This is how I am calling the service. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
$data.service("/api/program/getprograms", function (contextFactory) {
        var remotecontext = contextFactory();
        remotecontext.Program.filter("it.Program.ProgramID == '1'");

        context.Programs.forEach(function (program) {

            console.log(program);
        });
    });
```

I also tried:
    var remotedb = new AppContext({ provider: 'webApi', databaseName: 'RemoteDB', dataSource: '/api/program/getprograms' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data.service()` and `$data.initService()` was created to generate dynamic client-side data model on the fly. This is the alternative to generate static data model with JaySvcUtil.exe. 
This won't work with WebAPI endpoints and webApi provider since there is no metadata service in WebAPI. The $metadata service is available only in OData endpoints, for WebAPI, you have to build you client-side data model manually.